# Setting .access for subdomain using SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've a script in my host inside /public_html/assets/api/images/api.php or https://www.example.org/assets/api/images/api.php

Now I'm trying to alias it using .htaccess accessing by https://images.example.org

I had create an .htaccess into /home/mydomain/assets/api/images where I put this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^(.*) api.php?category=$2&id=$3&type=$4&size=$5&file=$6 [NC,QSA]
```

The .htaccess will receive urls with this syntax:

https://www.example.org/assets/api/images/**products/87/flyer/md/c4Nrlh_WyrrS-SBEFzwl.png**

But it doesn't work. The strings has passed empty values and I'm getting:

> category=&id=&type=&size=&file=

The full values is going only to $1 string without split to $2, $3, $4...

> produtos/87/flyer/md/c4Nrlh_WyrrS-SBEFzwl.png

Anybody can help me fixing it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+(\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))) api.php?&category=$1&id=$2&type=$3&size=$4&file=$5 [NC,QSA]
```